# Velocity template and contact form

Tags: javascript, html, apache, velocity

I am trying to make contact form alongside with velocity template to handle sending things from contact form to some address. Whole system is made on adobe experience manager CMS. I made formular with name attribute and now I need to take that attributes from contact form and parse it to address.

```
<div class="formular">
        <form method="post" action="/content/wwwmicrosites/wettbewerb/de/test-form/_jcr_content/parsys/htmlcontainer.sendmail.html">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstname">VORNAME</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastname">NACHNAME</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="adress">ADRESSE</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="adress">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="plz">PLZ</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="plz">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ort">ORT</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ort">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="emil">E-MAIL</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="emaul">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="date">GEBURTSDATUM</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="solution" value=""  type="hidden" name="solution">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" required>
                ICH HABE DIE <a href="#">TEILNAHMEBEDINGUNGEN </a>GELESEN UND BIN DAMIT EINVERSTANDEN
              </label>
            </div>
            <button id="submit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Weiter</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And need to connect it with velocity template. How can I make variables that will take values from contact form? And how to connect that things together.
I am trying to make all this work on adobe experience manager CMS.
This is my velocity template (mail.vm).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Template sent for quiz</h3>
        <p>
            Name :
             ${newMessage.firstname}
        </p>
        <p>
            Surname :
             ${newMessage.lastname}
        </p>
        <p>
            Adress :
             ${newMessage.adress}
        </p>
        <p>
            Plz :
             ${newMessage.plz}
        </p>
        <p>
            Ort :
             ${newMessage.ort}
        </p>
        <p>
            Email :
             ${newMessage.emaul}
        </p>
        <p>
            Date :
             ${newMessage.date}
        </p>
        <p>
            Solution:
             ${newMessage.solution}
        </p>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share how you are passing value to template?

Comment: I manage to find solution, it was on server side of AEM. Now it is solved. Thanks.